# Redis: Group & Sum multiple ZSET Sorted Sets into one Sorted Set

Tags: sorting, redis

If I have two sorted set with different set of members with different scores:

```
ZADD set1 10 "player1"
ZADD set1 15 "player2"
ZADD set1 5 "player3"

ZADD set2 30 "player1"
ZADD set2 22 "player3"
```

I need to merge the above 2 sets by grouping <s>the common</s> all players and summing up their scores and get like this:

```
set3 40 "player1"
set3 15 "player2"
set3 27 "player3"
```

One way I tried is to fetch this data into Ruby objects and do the grouping logic. I am looking for ways to do this within Redis.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're in luck because redis supports this out of the box!

> ZINTERSTORE destination numkeys key [key ...] [WEIGHTS weight] [AGGREGATE SUM|MIN|MAX]
>
> summary: Intersect multiple sorted sets and store the resulting sorted set in a new key

so in your case:

```
ZINTERSTORE set3 2 set1 set2 AGGREGATE SUM
```

and voila! set3 contains the common players with summed scores:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> ZRANGE set3 0 -1 WITHSCORES
1) "player3"
2) "27"
3) "player1"
4) "40"
```

Comment: thanks, I needed all players, not just the common ones.. so I used ZUNIONSTORE :)

Comment: @emaillenin your question said `grouping the common players and summing up their scores `. sounded like intersection, but as long as you found the way... BTW note that ZUNIONSTORE is a pretty expensive op in terms of CPU time if the sets are largs.

Comment: I have only about 1000 users now and I need to UNION about 5 to 6 sets.. Is there an alternate way to do it better when we scale?